# How to create and compile procedures in IBM db2

Tags: db2

I am new to db2. I have written procedures in oracle. 
I need to convert those procedures from oracle to db2.
I want to know how the procedures in db2 will be created and compiled.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A good walkthrough can be found [here](http://resources.devx.com/ibm/Article/28308).

But then you always have the redbooks that IBM puts out such as [this](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg246503.html) or [this](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg247083.html). 
It is worth pointing out this [migration tool](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/downloads/migration/mtk/) that you might find useful.